# Insert 2 output result sets from sp_spaceused into Temp Table (SQL Server non-2016)

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, stored-procedures, database-size, size

sp_spaceused, when executed without any parameters, produces 2 result sets

```
database_name, database_size, unallocated_size  
reserved, data, index_space, unused
```

Usually when you execute some SP, you can insert output into temp table like below example:

```
insert #temp (column1, column2, column3)
exec sp_someprocedure
```

but in case of sp_spaceused (without any parameters) - can not insert output, since it produces 2 result sets. 
I know 2016 has nice parameter @oneresultset = 1, but is there any way you can insert 2 or more output result sets into #temp in SQL 2014 or lower ?

Is there any tricks ?

Answer (score 1):

A trick to inserting two result sets into one table? No. I do not believe that is possible.

However, what I've done in the past, as I'm sure you have experimented with, is modify the code inside the stored procedure and create a custom version to deploy and call instead.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
CREATE TABLE #DatabaseSizes_4
(
    database_name NVARCHAR(128),
    database_size VARCHAR(18),
    unallocated_space VARCHAR(18),
    reserved VARCHAR(18),
    data VARCHAR(18),
    index_size VARCHAR(18),
    unused VARCHAR(18)
);

INSERT INTO #DatabaseSizes_4
EXEC sp_spaceused @oneresultset = 1

select * from #DatabaseSizes_4
```